# Почему nm не видит static глобальные переменные

Tags: global-variables, c++

Вопрос к поиску глобальных переменных. Почему команда nm пропускает static глобальные переменные из объектных файлов, например в коде одного из .cpp

```
static MapChToColor g_ChColor;
static MapColorToCh g_ColorCh;
static bool g_IsMapsFilled = false;             // guard of maps

static aPicture g_piInput;
static uint g_InputWidth = 0;
static uint g_InputHeight = 0;
```

вывод nm вообще их не содержит ни под каким флагом.
и еще, почему для некоторых файлов эта же команда пропускает ненужные вещи типа _ZN4Tree8FindNode5matchE, которые помечены флагом B?

Comment: Быть может, потому что эти переменные не используются?

Comment: компилятор мог и выбросить использование переменной, если там и так понятно. К примеру, у Вас есть две статическе переменные и они всегда равны. И изменяются синхронно. Компилятор может сократить.

Comment: Либо Вы транслируете с ключами оптимизации (например g++ -c -O3 t.cpp) и к этим переменным нет обращения, либо сами не обращаете внимание на то, что компилятор добавляет символ `_` перед имененем переменной

    00000050 b _g_InputWidth
    00000030 b _g_IsMapsFilled
    00000040 b _g_piInput
    ....

Comment: потому, что компилятор делает им "demangle" (даже не знаю, как правильно перевести. Запускайте nm с параметром `-C` (C большая) и будет счастье. Либо учитесь декодировать самостоятельно.

Comment: хм, действительно, я вывод с nm видимо грепил без b, а что делает параметр -C?

Comment: Люди, вы о чём? static -- не глобальные переменные.

Пардон, не так выразился. static -- они, конечно, глобальные, но не внешние. nm их видеть не может.

Comment: вообщем получилось так что nm их видит, они с флагом b как раз и появляются, но вместе с ними появляются также почему-то и некоторые константы (например строковые, или константы массивы)

Comment: Из ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (E)

     6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers
     3 If the declaration of a file scope identifier for an object or a function contains the storage-class specifier static, the identifier has internal linkage.22)

В C++ должны быть аналогичные строки.

А "b" -- символы из секции BSS (неинициализированная секция данных)

Comment: @pavlik_uhuhu, а какая у Вас ОС и компилятор? И `man nm` Вы прочитали?

--

Кроме того, Вы как бы сами с собой общаетесь. Мы ведь ни кода, ни вывода `nm` у Вас не видим.

Comment: ну почему же сам с собой, мне же помогли ваши ответы, я просто не замечал как nm выводит static переменные.
ос виндовз, компилил из под сигвина, gcc 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возьмём, например, такой код:

```
#include <string>    
using namespace std;

class TestClass{};

static int my_integer;
static string my_string;
static TestClass test;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Если прогнать его .o файл через nm следующим образом:

```
nm --demangle=gnu-v3 --defined-only
```

То получится следующий результат:

```
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .ctors
00000000 d .data
00000000 r .eh_frame
00000000 t .text
00000081 t _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
0000003a t __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)
00000004 b my_integer
0000000c b test
00000008 b my_string
00000000 b std::__ioinit
00000012 t __tcf_0
00000026 t __tcf_1
00000000 T main
```

Все статические переменные в данном файле присутствуют. Но есть одно НО. Если в файле присутствуют глобальные константы, то они тоже попадут в данный список.